# I want to convert Microsoft Word document to .txt format and save it in my solution folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, office-interop

I am using file uploader control and I need to convert the uploaded `.docx` file into `.txt`
file I used some of the code like below:

```
object missingType = Type.Missing;
object readOnly = true;
object isVisible = false;
object format = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatText;
string randomName = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/TextDoc/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
object fileName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
object txtFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/TextDoc/") + randomName + ".txt";
//Open the word document in background
ApplicationClass applicationclass = new ApplicationClass();
applicationclass.Documents.Open(ref fileName,
                                ref readOnly,
                                ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                                ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                                ref missingType, ref missingType, ref isVisible,
                                ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                                ref missingType, ref missingType);
applicationclass.Visible = false;
Document document = applicationclass.ActiveDocument;


//Save the word document as txt file
document.SaveAs(ref txtFilePath, ref format, ref missingType,
                ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                ref missingType);

//Close the word document
document.Close(ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType);
```

And I changed 'filename' variable to

```
object fileName = "~/" + Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload1.FileName);
```

then I am getting exception like:

```
This command is not available because no document is open.
```

Please any one help me..

Comment: Microsoft doesn't support office automation in ASP.Net: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Comment: I don't have a complete solution for your problem. However I've read that the office documents are now essentially just a zipped xml document. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DocX to read/manipulate word documents with no dependencies on Office or Interop.

Find DocX [Here](http://docx.codeplex.com/)

The project owner, Cathal Coffey posts on various DocX topics [HERE](http://www.cathalcoffey.ie/)

I did a quick and dirty "get started" type article on using DocX [HERE](http://typecastexception.com/post/2013/09/28/C-Create-and-Manipulate-Word-Documents-Programmatically-Using-DocX.aspx)

It should be relatively simple to use DocX to pull the text our of a Word doc and then save as a plain .txt file.

I don't normally just post links in an SO answer. In this case, however, since I am just pointing you to an alternative tool to get the job done, it seems appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I got those errors because of passing physical path to "Open method".

Finally I am taken an other folder in solution for storing uploaded word documents and i passed that
file path to "open method".I edited code like below:

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/WordDoc/")+Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
object fileName = Server.MapPath("~/WordDoc/"+Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
```

And I saved converted .txt files in an other Folder same as i did earlier(code is in question).
And after conversion i deleted the word document(which is uploaded or stored in "WordDoc" folder ) like:

```
File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/WordDoc/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try replacing the second argument (ref format) in the document.SaveAs method with the line below:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatUnicodeText
```

This will save your word document as a txt file.